# computer hard stops randomly

Tags: motherboard

I have a 5 year old dell desktop (that was the cheapest when I bought it).  Just recently it started hard stopping.  The monitor just goes black and the status light on the computer changes from green to orange.  I wasn't sure if this was a hardware problem or a software problem.  I figured I'd try installing (or at least running) ubuntu and see if that had a problem, but I can't get it to boot from CD.  I tried the windows installation CD as well.  It just won't boot.  I'm thinking maybe it is a hardware problem.  It's probably better to just call it a good 5 years and move on, but before I do - does anyone have any tips I should try before I pitch it?  I've already got the thing open.

Comment: Is optical disc drive boot enabled in BIOS?

Comment: Often pressing F12 during bootup will present boot drive options, choose "optical" or "CD/DVD".

Comment: yes, I did that.  I have to cd drives - I tried them both.  Neither of them worked.  One almost worked, but then not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1)** First check your CD/DVD Drive is working , it might be because of
>   dust.
>
> **2)** If possible try installing your OS using a USB PEN-drive
>
> **3)** Second Basic thing to do would be To disassemble everything in your
>   CPU Cabinet, clean them and Assemble
>   them back. Most of the my hardware
>   problems have been solved by this
>   method.
>
> **4)** Make sure you clean your RAM (the golden part) with a dry cloth. I
>   face sudden system stop like this
>   mainly in the monsoon season since
>   moisture gets inside the hardware

---

***Here are some tips to remember before throwing away your old computer***

- [5 Things You Must Check Before Disposing of Old Computers](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-check-disposing-computers/)
- [Things To Do before throwing away your Old PC](http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/things-to-do-before-throwing-away-your-old-pc.html)
- [Things You Can Do With Old  Monitors](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-computer-monitors/)
- [Things to do with an old computer](http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/things-to-do-with-an-old-computer/)

Answer (score 4):

Forget installing a new O/S on an unstable system. (Which, by the way, points to a hardware issue).

If you have an Ubuntu install CD, just boot to the memtest86+ test. If memory errors are found, you either have bad memory or a bad motherboard.

Comment: He said he can't boot from CD ...

Comment: See comments under question.

Answer (score 1):

Last-gasp efforts before throwing it away :

- Have a professional clean it internally (he will get at places you won't, and will tell you more about the problem)
- Try another CD drive

However, 5 years is old age for a computer.

Comment: "5 years is old age for a computer" This is true for low-end (when new) and poorly cared-for computers, but with proper care and a little organ replacement (new hard drive and RAM upgrade) 5 years can be merely Middle Aged.

Comment: @kmarsh: Sorry doctor, but to quote from the post: "that was the cheapest when I bought it". Replacing parts here can be a case of "operation success patient died".